# How to use an HTML form user input in a python function

Tags: python, html, django, forms

So I'm working in developing a web page to my project, so my question is, given user input in the html form, how can I use that input to call a python function (the function receives the string as a parameter). Keep in mind that I'll be using Django to run everything when I'm done with this. Following with the html form I'm currently using (I'm really new to html, so any feedback is welcome).

```
<form>
    Sequente:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="sequente", placeholder="a,f,a->b,b->c,c->d,d->e|-e", method='get'>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You don't call a Python function from HTML. You use the `action` attribute of the form element to submit your form to a URL, which maps to a Django view containing your Python code.

Comment: So, exactly what action do I use in the action attribute?

Comment: Like I said, you use a URL, ie one you have defined in your urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

`method` is an attribute of `form` tag not `input`. Based on your usage, a get or post (usually) request is sent to the django. Based on what you have added, to the same url that you have got the form template from. 
The sequence of actions will be like this:
request sent from browser -> django receives the request -> match it in the `urls.py` -> call the view function (or class) that the url is pointing toward -> your view (python function) is triggered.

Comment: Thanks, but how exactly do I grab the request in urls.py to call the function?

Comment: just watch a tutorial. This usually will be one of the first things they cover. However, your view wll be this way: `def some_view(request)`, you can get the details of the request in the `request` arguement.